# How to randomize a to p without repitition

Tags: c

I want to randomize a to p without repetition.

```
int main(){
    int array2[4][4];
    bool arr[100]={0};
    int i;
    int j;

    srand(time(NULL));
    for(i=0; i<=3; i++){

        for(j=0; j<=3; j++){
            int randomNumber1;
            randomNumber1 = (rand() % (82-65+1))+65;
        
            if (!arr[randomNumber1])
            {
                printf("%c ",randomNumber1);
                array2[i][j]=randomNumber1;
            }
            else
            {
                i--;
                j--;
                arr[randomNumber1]=1;
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return;
```

the output still has repeat alphabet. I want to have the output in 4x4 with with all a to p without it repeating.

Comment: rand() function doesn't guarantee unique values in subsequent calls. For your case, you need to build a logic such that it regenerates if the character was previously encountered.

Comment: Do a fisher-yates shuffle on an array containing the things you want to randomize.

Comment: a to p. my bad forgot to change it . edit: my bad again.

Comment: I don't know how to use fisher-yates shuffle and I don't understand how to use it

Comment: [Fisher–Yates shuffle @ wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) (look at "_The modern algorithm_")

Comment: I don't understand it. Sorry

Comment: mostly I saw  fisher-yates shuffle example for numbers and not alphabet. so it is quite hard for me to understand on how to use it for alphabet

Comment: 1. Create an array of items to pick from. 2. Randomly pick a item from the array. 3. Remove that item from the array. 4. Repeat with the smaller array until you have one left. 5. Remaining item is the one left to be the final item. (in this case the array starts off as "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

Comment: The wikipedia page for fisher-yates has code, explanation, and some worked-through examples using letters. If you want help, you'll have to provide more than "I don't understand it" and claiming you've only seen it work for numbers.

Answer (score 1):

There are some errors in your code. IMHO the most serious is that `arr[randomNumber1]=1;` is is the wrong branch of the test. That means that your current code does not invalidate once a  number was used but only if it has already been invalidated => if you control the `arr` array at the end of the program all value are still 0.

That is not all. When you get a duplicate, you should only reset the inner loop, and you are currently off by 2 in your maximum ascii code: you go up to `R` when you want to stop at `P`.

Your code should be:

```
for (i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {

    for (j = 0; j <= 3; j++) {
        int randomNumber1;
        randomNumber1 = (rand() % (81 - 65)) + 65;

        if (!arr[randomNumber1])
        {
            printf("%c ", randomNumber1);
            array2[i][j] = randomNumber1;
            arr[randomNumber1] = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            //i--;
            j--;
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

But this kind of code is terribly inefficient. In my tests it took 30 to 60 steps to fill 16 values, because random can return duplicates. This is the reason why you were advised in comments to use instead the *modern algorithm* for [Fisher-Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle):

```
int main() {
    int array2[16];
    unsigned i, j, k=0;

    // initialize array with alphabets from A to P
    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(array2); i++) {
        array2[i] = 'A' + i;
    }
    // Use Fisher-Yates shuffle on the array
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (i = 15; i > 0; i--) {
        j = rand() % (i + 1);
        if (j != i) {
            int c = array2[i];
            array2[i] = array2[j];
            array2[j] = c;
        }
    }
    // Display a 4x4 pattern
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            printf("%c ", array2[k++]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Which shuffles the array in only 16 steps.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the outline

```
// Need some #includes here - exercise for the reader
char items[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
int len = sizeof(items);
srand(time(NULL));

while (len > 0) {
   int r = rand() % len;
   printf("%c", items[r]);
   len--;
   items[r] = items[len];
}
```

This should do the trick to print the whole alphabet in random order without repeats. Modify to do what you need it to do

Comment: @TedLyngmo - Would `sizeof` be better than `strlen`

Comment: Nah, that'd include the null terminator and probably not be a good fit for OP anyway. I think it's very fine as it is.

Comment: @TedLyngmo  Gave you a +1 for your help and insights

Comment: Much obliged! You got my vote as soon as I saw the solution. Clean and simple!